# How to get width of a string in java

Tags: java

I just started my comp science course and 3 weeks in I am already struggling. Using `BlueJ` I need to create a rectangle, with methods label, height of the rectangle, colour of the rectangle, position of both label and rectangle and width of rectangle. It basically has to look like a bar chart with text to the left of it therefore I need to figure out the width of the text in pixels so then i can subtract it from the `x` position of the rectangle. I have had no experience with java or programming to draw on a canvas before therefore I would need some sort of `label.getWidth();` command

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Are you sure you're not just being asked to model a rectangle as opposed to drawing it? A computer science course that jumps into graphical user interfaces in week 3 seems strange / poorly designed.

Answer (score 2):

The width of text depends on the font you are using.  For example, five characters can look like:

iiiii

mmmmm

in a variable width font (an 'i' is not as wide as an 'm').

In a fixed width font, five characters are always the same width:

```
iiiii

mmmmm
```

So, to keep it simple, switch to a fixed-width font (say Courier) count the number of characters and multiply by the width of a single character.

Similar calculations are possible with a variable-width font, but more complex.